# How to convert a numpy array string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have the following numpy array

```
array(['2/25/2019 9:55:01 PM', '2/25/2019 10:00:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:05:00 PM', '2/25/2019 10:10:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:15:00 PM', '2/25/2019 10:20:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:25:00 PM', '2/25/2019 10:30:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:35:00 PM', '2/25/2019 10:40:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:45:00 PM', '2/25/2019 10:50:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 10:55:00 PM', '2/25/2019 11:00:00 PM',
       '2/25/2019 11:05:00 PM', '2/25/2019 11:10:00 PM'], dtype=object)
```

All the date inside this numpy array are type `str`. Now I want to convert all the element in this numpy array from type `str` to `datetime`.

I know that I can do it by using a loop, but because the size of the numpy array is very large, so is there any method that I can convert them without using iteration?

Comment: Conversion to `datetime.datetime` objects has to be in a loop.  Conversion to `np.datetime64` dtype can be done with `astype`, if the string format is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
your_array = pd.to_datetime(your_array).to_numpy()
```